# Running a single Emacs instance

Tags: start-up, process

I'd like to set in my dot-emacs a function to detect if an Emacs instance is already running, possibly exiting Emacs informing user.

To do this I should query the OS for running processes. However

```
(list-processes)
```

does not return OS processes,  but only those started by Emacs.
How can I achieve the intended objective?

Comment: I think this needs to happen at the OS level.  Are you sure you're not interested in running the Emacs daemon and connecting to it?

Comment: @Dan: I to not explicitly need `(server-start)`. However using it with `(server-running-p)` could be a workaround.

Comment: `(server-running-p)` is the way to go. There are ways to get process ids. That is operating system dependent. E.g., under Linux one could inspect `/proc`.

Comment: `list-system-processes` would also be an option